# Chrome driver not working on centos 7

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I m unable to run my test cases using chrome browser on centos 7. i m using chromedriver version 2.30.477691
and chrome binary version

```
 # google-chrome -version
Google Chrome 59.0.3071.109
```

running the testcases with root so tried --no-sandbox option didnt work . also tried with no such options in command line.

Please help.

```
[root@Server ~]# time xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1024x768x24" java
-jar  Project.jar  -Dwebdriver.chrome.binary=/usr/bin/google-chrome --no-sandbox
```

Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57) on port 26527 Only local connections are allowed. Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: **chrome not reachable**   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux
    3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout:
    114.41 seconds

Comment: how did you install chromebinary and chromedriver, mention that also? Do you have these inside /usr/bin directory?